# Obtain paths of folders not containing a pdf file

Tags: python, list, path, os.walk

I want to find all the folders that **do not** contain a pdf document inside of them.

This is what I have tried so far

```
import os 

path = 'T:/Projects/'

paths_not_containing_pdfs = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if not name.endswith('.pdf'):
            paths_not_containing_pdfs.append(root)
```

However, this code doesn't work. It pretty much returns the path to all the folders. And not the only ones without pdfs.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if not name.endswith('.pdf'):
            paths_not_containing_pdfs.append(root)
```

does find all folders which do have at least one non-PDF file, to find these which do not have any PDF you might use `any` as follows

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if not any(name.endswith('.pdf') for name in files):
        paths_not_containing_pdfs.append(root)
```

Note that I used so-called comprehension, `name.endswith('.pdf') for name in files` gives `True`s (for .pdf) and `False`s (for other), then `any` check if at least one `True` appeared.

Comment: Exactly this! Thanks @Daweo